# A Framework with Common Functionality Built-in

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, content-management-system, enterprise

My team is about to start a new project and we are currently in the researching phase.  We are wondering if there was a framework or some product that has the common functionalities built-in.  Functions such as user management, extensible data storage and UI management would be considered common functionalities.  Then we only need to focus on the business logic.

What we want is something more higher-level than writing a Java 2 EE/Spring app from scratch (which gives us almost no functionality but lots of flexibility) but not quite as rigid as a CMS (which gives us a lot of functionality but if it's not functionality that you need, it is hard to customize).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/). It is a lot lighter weight than Java 2 EE/Spring. A great framework for the web, and a lot of the built in functionality you are looking for is available available modules.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29)).  It provides a lot of common functionality out of the box with little hassle, while still allowing you to drop down into Spring/Hibernate/etc. if necessary.